# How to create an struct pointer in another class?

Tags: c++, object, data-structures, linked-list

I have 3 classes: Book,Student,LibrarySystem and i need 3 linkedlists to store data, first linkedList is called Node which stores Students, second linkedList is called studenBookNode which stores the books reserved by specific student and my third linkedList is allBooksNode which stores the created book objects
here is my implementation below:

```
class Book {
public:
    Book();
    Book(int id, string title, int year);
    ~Book();
    //some getter and setter functions
private:
    int bookId;
    string bookName;
    int bookYear;
    bool status;
};

class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(int id, string name);
    ~Student();
    Student(const Student& rightVal);
    //Student& operator=(const Student& rightVal);
    int getId();
    void setId(int id);
    string getName();
    void setName(string name);
    //studentBookNode methods
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getLength() const;
    bool removeNode(int index);
    int findIndex(int studentId);
    struct studentBookNode {
        Book item;
        studentBookNode* next;
    };
    studentBookNode* stuhead;
    int studentBooks;
    studentBookNode* findPointer(int index) const;

private:
    int studentId;
    string studentName;
};

class LibrarySystem {
public:
    LibrarySystem();
    ~LibrarySystem();
    void addStudent(const int studentId, const string studentName);
    void addBook(const int bookId, const string bookName, const int bookYear);

    void deleteBook(const int bookId);
    void deleteStudent(const int studentId);
    void checkoutBook(const int bookId, const int studentId);
    void returnBook(const int bookId);
    void showAllBooks() const;
    void showBook(const int bookId) const;
    void showStudent(const int studentId) const;

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isBooksEmpty() const;
    bool removeNode(int index);
    bool removeBookNode(int index);

    int findBookIndex(int bookId);
    int findIndex(int studentId);
    int getLengthBooks() const;
    int getLength() const;

private:
    struct Node {
        Student item;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    int Size;
    Node* findPointer(int index) const;
    struct allBooksNode {
        Book item;
        allBooksNode* next;
    };
    allBooksNode* bookHead;
    int bookSize;
    allBooksNode* findBookPointer(int index) const;
};
```

I have a method checkOutBook in LibrarySystem and i need to access studentBookNode in the method, first im checking the availability of studentId and bookId's and then if they are available i need to add the book to the specific students studentBookNode but i could not access it because of the scope how can i fix this, here is my implementation below:

```
void LibrarySystem::checkoutBook(const int bookId, const int studentId)
{
    bool bookExist = false;
    bool studentExist = false;
    Node* cur = head;
    int stuIndex;
    int bookIndex;
    allBooksNode* curBook = bookHead;
    for (int i = 1; i <= getLengthBooks(); i++) {
        if (curBook->item.getBookId() == bookId) {
            bookExist = true;
            bookIndex = i;
        }
        curBook = curBook->next;
    }
    if (bookExist) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= getLength(); i++) {
            if (cur->item.getId() == studentId) {
                studentExist = true;
                stuIndex = i;
            }
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Book :" << bookId << " does not exist for checkout" << endl;
    }
    if (bookExist == true && studentExist == true) {
        Node* stuTemp = findPointer(stuIndex);
        allBooksNode* bookTemp = findBookPointer(bookIndex);

        if (stuTemp->item.getLength() == 0) {
            //problem is here i cant create studentBookNode* here
          studentBookNode* temp = new studentBookNode();
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Student: " << studentId << " does not exist for checkout" << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried to create a pointer to studentBookNode as:

```
studentBookNode* temp = new studentBookNode();
```

And the error message is

```
studentBookNode was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Do you know many books that can change their name or edition year during their lifetime? Just asking.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. i could not understand your question

Comment: It is something completely tangent to your question but still. You have `setBookName()` and `setBookYear()`. What are these functions for? Could a library manager wake up one morning and decide that from now on "How to bomb-proof your kitten, 2013" should be called "Throwing vegetables at people for fun and profit, 1886"?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.Ah sir, this code is for university assignment it is forbidden to change the get/set methods, my question is how can i access studenBookNode in LibrarySystem class?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. How a about fixing typos or incorrect data?

Comment: Not to the question. "i could not access it " what does this mean exactly? You tried to access it how? and then what happened? You need to post code that caused an error, and paste the exact output or error message verbatim. A comment "I tried to do something here" is useless. Show what you have tried, and what was the result.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. i edited the post, the problem is i can not access the studentBookNode because of the scope

Comment: @t.niese That's a good comment, but how are we supposed to keep track of books if every single thing about them can be changed?

Comment: @drescherjm nope struct is called as studentBookNode as it is shown in implementation above.

Comment: Where do you have `studentBookNode* temp = new studentBookNode();` in your code? If it is not inside the `Student` class you have to `Student::studentBookNode* temp = new Student::studentBookNode();`

Comment: @drescherjm in the method checkOutBook below the commented line.

Comment: I see now. The answer is correct.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you very much.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sure if everything can be changed and there is a chance that this is abused or could introduce more errors, then this might be a problem. But such a thing (in case that it is stored persistently) would be solved with an audit log that keeps track of the changes. Anyhow out of my experience, you can never expect that a dataset is free of errors and that there will be always be a need to corret such errors. Besides that there are book titles that have been changed (but I don't know if the ISBN there also changed which would be a new book entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`studentBookNode` is a member of class `Student`. Unless you are writing a member of class `Student`, this name can be only accessed as `Student::studentBookNode`.